# XSD validation for unsorted and only one unbounded item

Tags: xsd

I have a xml file like this:

```
<customer>
  <field1 />
  <field2 />
  <field3>
    <item1 />
  </field3>
  <field3>
    <item1 />
  </field3>
</customer>
```

field* can appear in any order and only field3 can appear more than once.

How can I create a XSD file to validate this?

Thank you!

Comment: There certainly _is_ a question.

Comment: There was not a question when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

### Try this

I'm not a guru, but this appears to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="customer" type="customerType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="customerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="field1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="field2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="field3" type="field3Type"
                  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="field3Type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="item1">
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### tools

I used [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net), but there are loads of editors which will validate XML.

### links

You might also be interested in [this article](http://sqlmusings.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/generating-xsd-from-an-xml-file/) about generating an XSD from an XML file.

Comment: AJ, Thanks for your answer. But the problem is that field* may appear in any order - xs:all would be perfect if I could use maxOccurs="unbounded".

Answer (score 0):

Hum, this is the kind of work xsd is really not handy for. Anyway, this should do the trick if I did not make a mistake:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <element name="customer" type="tns:customerType"/>
  <complexType name="customerType">
    <sequence>
      <element>
        <complexType>
          <all>
            <element>
              <complexType>
                <sequence>
                  <element ref="tns:field3" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <element ref="tns:field1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </sequence>
              </complexType>
            </element>
            <element>
              <complexType>
                <sequence>
                  <element ref="tns:field3" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <element ref="tns:field2" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </sequence>
              </complexType>
            </element>
            <element>
              <complexType>
                <sequence>
                  <element ref="tns:field3" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <element ref="tns:field4" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </sequence>
              </complexType>
            </element>
          </all>
        </complexType>
      </element>
      <element ref="tns:field3" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="field1Container"/>
  <complexType name="field2Container"/>
  <complexType name="field3Type">
    <sequence>
      <element name="item1"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="field4Container"/>
  <element name="field3" type="tns:field3Type"/>
  <element name="field1"/>
  <element name="field2"/>
  <element name="field4"/>
</schema>
```